# PHP: (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key]) or (@$array[$key])?

Tags: php

For when I am only interested in if `$array[$key]` has a non-empty value, but `$array[$key]` is not guaranteed to exist.

Is there an advantage or preference to doing it one way over the other?

Full example:

```
if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key]) {
    // Do something
}
```

vs

```
if (@$array[$key]) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: @array[$key] will hide only the error messages you have not to use that that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(@) Error Control Operator**

- PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When
  prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be
  generated by that expression will be ignored.
- The @-operator works only on expressions. A simple rule of thumb is:
  if you can take the value of something, you can prepend the @
  operator to it. For instance, you can prepend it to variables,
  function and include calls, constants, and so forth. You cannot
  prepend it to function or class definitions, or conditional
  structures such as if and foreach, and so forth.

**isset** — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

- If a variable has been unset with unset(), it will no longer be set.
  isset() will return FALSE if testing a variable that has been set to
  NULL. Also note that a null character ("\0") is not equivalent to the
  PHP NULL constant.
- If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE
  only if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to
  right and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered.

**Checking** Array key value is not empty :

```
if(empty($fields_array[$key])) {
    //You will be here if  value does not exist or is FALSE
}
```